# How to split in ansible

Tags: split, ansible

I'm relatively new to ansible but I'm trying to convert some of my python scripts to ansible playbooks and am having a hard time understanding how to assign variables to then loop through. I have a playbook that runs show vlan brief:

```
---
- name: Get ARP information
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false


  tasks:
    - name: show vlan brief
      raw: "show vlan brief | i test"
      register: vlan_output

    - debug: var=vlan_output.stdout_lines
```

This gives the following output:

```
PLAY [Get ARP information] *****************************************************

TASK [show vlan brief] *********************************************************
changed: [sw1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [sw1] => {
    "vlan_output.stdout_lines": [
        "100  test                             active    Gi0/3, Gi0/1, Gi0/2",
        "101  test2                            active    "
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
sw1                        : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I want to only grab the vlan number, in this case it would be 100 & 101, and then loop through and do a "show mac address table | inc VLAN_NUM"

I tried adding splits to the register & debug lines but keep getting errors back that say:

```
#split added
- debug: var=vlan_output.stdout_lines.split(' ')

#return error
"vlan_output.stdout_lines.split(\" \")": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

In python I would loop through the items and split the strings to get what i needed. What is the preferred or equivalent to that process in ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *`Run command:`*

```
"show mac address-table | include <VLAN_NUMBER>"
```

Try this

```
    - set_fact:
        my_vlan_numbers: "{{ vlan_output.stdout_lines|
                             map('regex_replace', myregex, myreplace)|
                             list }}"
      vars:
        myregex: '^(\S*) (.*)$'
        myreplace: '\1'
    - shell:
        cmd: "show mac address-table | include {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_vlan_numbers }}"
```

---

Details of *`myregex`*

```
^ ..... match beginning of the line
(\S*) . first group of any non-space chars
      . match space
(.*) .. second group of any chars
$ ..... match end of the line
```

Details of the *`replace`*

```
\1 .... backreference the first group of myregex
```

Comment: That worked but I can't for the life of my figure out how/why..... have any good links that explain that process?

Comment: See Python RegEx. For example https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: And then how would I use that variable in other sections of my playbook. For example, the next step is to run a "show mac address-table | include <VLAN_NUMBER>".

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer to show how to assign my_vlan_numbers under the debug.

Comment: See the updated answer. Open a new question if any.